# limiting css viewport scaling to 800px

Tags: html, css, viewport

My `CSS` is designed to be mobile first, so everything is dependent on the `viewport` using `vh` and `vw`. For Desktop use, I would like to limit the scaling to be within `800px` and center it. Is there a way to constrain the `viewport` to max at `800px`? and how would I center it?

Comment: Just constraint the width of the html or the body

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa when it set html or body or a div container to { max-width: 800px; } it only constrains the <p> tag, doesn't effect h2, button, or video tags. Any idea why, or how to constrain those as well?

Comment: try `max-width:100%` on the children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport), you can determine the min-width and max-width of your viewport, for instance

```
@viewport {
  min-width: 640px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

For maximum browser support, you can define the min and max-width of html and body like this

```
html, body {
  min-width: 640px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: highly not supported by most browsers